# How to detect consecutive values above a threshold?

Tags: r

I have data for which I would like to apply a rolling function to detect at which point a value is greater than a speficic threshold.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(
  x = 1:10,
  y = c(1, 3, 4, 1, 5, 34, 43, 1, 45, 3)
)

df
#> # A tibble: 10 x 2
#>        x     y
#>    <int> <dbl>
#>  1     1     1
#>  2     2     3
#>  3     3     4
#>  4     4     1
#>  5     5     5
#>  6     6    34
#>  7     7    43
#>  8     8     1
#>  9     9    45
#> 10    10     3
```

What I would like is to find the row for which the next 2 values are higher than a certain threshold (say 30). This would produce this:

```r
tibble(
  x = 1:10,
  y = c(1, 3, 4, 1, 5, 34, 43, 1, 45, 3),
  i = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE)
)
#> # A tibble: 10 x 3
#>        x     y i    
#>    <int> <dbl> <lgl>
#>  1     1     1 FALSE
#>  2     2     3 FALSE
#>  3     3     4 FALSE
#>  4     4     1 FALSE
#>  5     5     5 FALSE
#>  6     6    34 TRUE 
#>  7     7    43 FALSE
#>  8     8     1 FALSE
#>  9     9    45 FALSE
#> 10    10     3 FALSE
```

I have a large dataset (few millions lines) so I am trying to find a efficient solution. Maybe using `data.table`?
<sup>Created on 2019-02-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1)** Use `rollapply` to roll over each consecutive pair checking if they are both above the threshold:

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)

df %>% mutate(i = rollapply(y > 30, 2, all, align = "left", fill = FALSE))

# A tibble: 10 x 3
       x     y i    
   <int> <dbl> <lgl>
 1     1     1 FALSE
 2     2     3 FALSE
 3     3     4 FALSE
 4     4     1 FALSE
 5     5     5 FALSE
 6     6    34 TRUE 
 7     7    43 FALSE
 8     8     1 FALSE
 9     9    45 FALSE
10    10     3 FALSE
```

**2)** Another approach is to use `lead`:

```
df %>% mutate(i = y > 30 & lead(y) > 30)
```

Comment: Maybe `lead(y, default = FALSE)` to avoid the last value being set to `NA` if the two last values are above threshold.

Answer (score 2):

`data.table` version of the tidyverse version from @G. Grothendieck:

```
dt <- as.data.table(df)

thresh <- 30

dt[, i := y > thresh & shift(y, -1L, fill = FALSE) > thresh][]

     x  y     i
 1:  1  1 FALSE
 2:  2  3 FALSE
 3:  3  4 FALSE
 4:  4  1 FALSE
 5:  5  5 FALSE
 6:  6 34  TRUE
 7:  7 43 FALSE
 8:  8  1 FALSE
 9:  9 45 FALSE
10: 10  3 FALSE
```

credit to @Henrik for the shorter expression for `i`. I needed to update `data.table` to use it (old version didn't take negative values for the `n` argument)

Comment: Or slightly shorter: `i := y > thresh & shift(y, -1L, fill = FALSE) > thresh`

Comment: Would it be possible to **also** verify that the previous 2 observations are below a threshold?

Comment: yes, using `i := y > thresh & shift(y, -1L, fill = FALSE) & shift(y, -2L, fill = FALSE)` should do so